# Django / Mezzanine: 500 error when updating page or blog (and DEBUG=False only)

Tags: django, mezzanine

I have just deployed a Mezzanine instance on Elastic Beanstalk and all is working fine when DEBUG  = True.

When DEBUG = False however, I am bounced to the 500 error page whenever I am in the admin section of the site and "Save" something (a page, or blog for example).  Other than that, the rest of the site works perfectly - it's reading everything from the database, serving up compressed JS/CSS etc.

Things I have already checked:
- ALLOWED_HOSTS is now set correctly
- There are no console errors for missing JS files
- The log file just shows what is below:

```
172.31.17.189 (73.222.4.136) - - [08/Jun/2016:04:09:35 +0000] "POST /admin/blog/blogpost/1/change/ HTTP/1.1" 500 6317 "http://tenzo-www.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/blog/blogpost/1/change/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
```

I'd welcome thoughts.  Perhaps you can just even tell me how to get better logging while DEBUG=False? I don't see anything in access_log or error_log that's saying anything about this error.

Answer (score 0):

Actually managed to fix my own problem - two fold answer:

1) To enable better debugging while DEBUG=False, I suggest the following in your settings.py:

```
SERVER_EMAIL = 'server@xxx.com'
ADMINS = (('Name', 'xxx@xxx.com'),)
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS = True
```

Then you'll get a nice email showing you the error!

2) The actual error was caused because django-htmlmin doesn't play nice with Mezzanine. It adds content around the response that breaks it.

Hope it helps someone.